# Override pure virtual method with parallel base class method?

Tags: c++, overriding, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

Say I have class `Foo` with a pure virtual function `say` and class `Bar` with a method `say` and I want to implement class `FooBar` which inherits from `Foo` and `Bar` with `Foo::say` being overrode by `Bar::say`. I could do something as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    virtual void say() = 0;
};

class Bar {
public:
    void say() {
        std::cout <<"I am a Bar." << std::endl;
    }
};

class FooBar : public Foo, public Bar {
public:
    void say() override {
        Bar::say();
    }
};

int main() {
    FooBar foobar;
    foobar.say();  // I want to print "I am a Bar."
    return 0;
}
```

But this just makes `FooBar::say` a function that calls `Bar::say`. It is a very minor annoyance but is there a way to actually just make `FooBar` override `Foo::say` directly with `Bar::say`? Would making `FooBar::say` `inline` reliably accomplish this? I realize I could make `Bar` inherit from `Foo` and `FooBar` inherit only from `Bar` but this would not be appropriate in the actual project this example is an analogous to.

Comment: Inline is just an help for the optimizer. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: That's why I asked "reliably." If my compiler actually replaces calls to `FooBar::say()` with calls to `Bar::say()` then that would accomplish exactly what I desire, but I don't know if that solution is reliable or not, I.E. how often the compiler will actually obey it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

class ISay {
public:
    virtual void say() = 0;
};

class Bar: public virtual ISay {
public:
    void say() override {
        std::cout <<"I am a Bar." << std::endl;
    }
};

class FooBar : public virtual ISay, public Bar {};

int main() {
    FooBar foobar;
    foobar.say();  // Prints "I am a Bar."
}
```

This is known as **dominance** in virtual inheritance.

Some argue that in order to support this, one should always inherit interfaces virtually.

---

Virtual inheritance has two main costs (well maybe more):

- Initialization of the virtually inherited common class sub-object, that upmost base class, is specified in the most derived class. Specifications in classes intermediate in the inheritance chain(s), are ignored.
- There can be some overhead for member function calls, because the `this` pointer may have to be adjusted.

Comment: I don't know why the horizontal line disappears in the answer. At least in my Firefox. Mysterious.

Comment: What is the gain here compared to making `Bar` inherit from `ISay` and `FooBar` simply inherit from `Bar`?

Comment: @super: ITYM compared to no additional inheritance of `ISay`. The general situation is that `FooBar` inherits from some abstract class that inherits from `ISay`, and that `FooBar` drags in an implementation by inheriting also from `Bar`. I know, the names here are not perfect.

Comment: "_public virtual ISay, public Bar_" why "public virtual ISay" here?

Comment: @curiousguy: You can replace that with inheritance of an abstract class that isn't a pure interface but drags in `ISay`.