# Muiltple inheritance: first base class dependent on function in the second base class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a lot of different child classes (15+) that all have the same function `centerAt` defined inside of them. Those child classes each inherits a different classes in an extern library: what is mutual for all of them is that they have the function `setPos` that centerAt is dependent on.

My goal is to avoid code repetition and I therefore came up with a solution moving centerAt to a base class that all the child class could inherit along side with the base classes from the external library: multiple inheritance.

I came up with this code

```
class InternalBase {
public:
    void centerAt(int x, int y) {
        // Do some math
        setPos(newx, newy)
    }
    virtual void setPos() = 0; // Should be replaced by the setPos in ExternalBase
};

// There are 15+ different external base classes used, here only 2 are shown
class ExternalBase1 { // this is from an external library
public:
    void setPos() { /* internal definition */} 
};

class ExternalBase2 { // this is from an external library
public:
    void setPos() { /* internal definition */} 
};
class Child1 : public InternalBase, public ExternalBase1 {
public:
    // A lot of different functions
};

class Child2 : public InternalBase, public ExternalBase2 {
public:
    // A lot of different functions
};

int main() {
    Child1 myobj;
    myobj.centerAt(120, 394);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the object can't be constructed: the compiler complaining that is an abstract class - probably because `setPos` weren't inherited from `ExternalBase1`. How can I fix this, so `Child1` inherits `setPos` from `ExternalBase1` and `InternalBase`thereby can use the `setPos` defined in `ExternalBase1`.

This issue is identical to [Override pure virtual method with parallel base class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907742/override-pure-virtual-method-with-parallel-base-class-method), but the big knot is, that because I am dealing with an external library, it is not possible to use the given solution (making `ExternalBase1` inherit `InternalBase` first: `class ExternalBase1: public virtual InternalBase`).

I would like to avoid the use of templates.

Comment: Except that using templates is the cleanest solution. Unless you really like typing a lot of code, only to end up reimplementing the same wheel that templates already implement for you. Additionally, the shown code is fake. The virtual `setPos()` obviously takes two parameters.

Comment: If the only thing that InternalBase is providing is the definition of centerAt, make ExternalBase<number> inherit from it, then make any Child<number> inherit from ExternalBase

Comment: any chance you can make your example (at least visually) smaller ?

Comment: You can also make centerAt a free function expecting an object, which inherits from a base class defining a setPos.

Answer (score 1):

Using templates is the simplest solution. Templates are one of the distinct features of C++ and there's no reason not to use them.

```
template<typename T>
class ExternalBaseMixin : public InternalBase, public T {

public:
    using T::T;

    void setPos(int x, int y) override
    {
        T::setPos(x, y);
    }
};
```

That's it. Then, it's simply a matter of:

```
class Child1 : public ExternalBaseMixin<ExternalBase1> {

// ...

class Child2 : public ExternalBaseMixin<ExternalBase2> {

// ...
```

etc...

There is no comparable built-in, non-template C++ feature that accomplishes the same thing. Any non-template solution will end up doing the exact same thing that this does, but with much more typing, more code, and with a more error-prone result. This is fairly bulletproof, as long as a single requirement gets met: always inherit from `ExternalBaseMixin`. As long as that happens everything gets overriden and combined together, in the proper order. Plus, this also guarantees inheritance order: that `InternalBase` gets constructed before the external class, if that matters.

Comment: Maybe
```template<typename T>
class InternalBase : public T {}

class Child1: public InternalBase<ExternalBase>```
Would be simpler?

Comment: If you want to do that, it would be equivalent but it will result in slightly more code bloat. Each template instance will have its own implementation of `centerAt`. That's not the end of the world by itself. But, with this approach, it makes it possible to dump more code into `InternalBase`, and not have it multiply like rabbits.

Comment: Thanks for your experienced knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CRTP and make `InternalBase` a template type
.

This introduces very little changes to your code.

```cpp
template <class Derived>
class InternalBase {
public:
    void centerAt(int x, int y) {
        // Do some math
        Derived& derived = static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
        derived.setPos(x, y);
    }
};

class ExternalBase1 { 
public:
    void setPos(int x, int y) {} 
};

class Child1 : public InternalBase<Child1>, public ExternalBase1 {
};

int main() {
    Child1 myobj;
    myobj.centerAt(120, 394);
    return 0;
}
```

See it work here: https://godbolt.org/z/Tsej4Gcfd

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for your problem is just explicitly defining on each child the setPos() function to use. (I adjusted some ill defined code that I guess comes from this being an example, but setPos and the virtual definitions provided did not match in signature):

```
#include <iostream>

class InternalBase {
public:
    void centerAt(int x, int y) {
        // Do some math
        setPos(x, y);
    }
    virtual void setPos(int x, int y) = 0;
};

class ExternalBase1 {
public:
    void setPos(int x, int y) { std::cout << "Inside ExternalBase1::setPos" << std::endl; } 
};

class Child1 : public InternalBase, public ExternalBase1 {
public:
    void setPos(int x, int y) { ExternalBase1::setPos(x, y); } 
    // A lot of different functions
};

int main() {
    Child1 myobj;
    myobj.centerAt(120, 394);
    return 0;
}
```

Although I would suggest, if you have the time, to try to solve the problem structuring the code from a different approach (templates are ideal here, as already someone answered).